# imshow shows rotated image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I'm using Matlab to show the frames in a video sequence , below is my code:

```
seq=sprintf('walk%d.avi',v);   % video's name
videoReader = vision.VideoFileReader(seq);
vidObj = VideoReader(seq);
numFrames = vidObj.NumberOfFrames
for i = 1:numFrames 
    frame = step(videoReader); % read the next video frame
    imshow(frame)
end
```

Actually it worked fine previously, and i have no idea since when and what caused it to show rotated image . Hope you guys can help me. thank you.

Comment: Rotated (by how much) or flipped?

Comment: Matlab shows images like a matrix with the first coordinate (rows) going top-down and the second (columns) left-right. If your images are in a x-y convention, they will appear rotated by 180˚.

Comment: @AdiShavit it is rotated by 180 degree. Hi Cade,i have tried with different file type like mp4, mpeg, it showed correct orientation. Is it due to the file type ?

Comment: Images often have the Y-axis pointing downward (like rows), as opposed to Matlab where the Y-axis points upward. These inconsistencies can cause a horizontal flip. Don't know where the rotation (or extra vertical flip) comes from.

Comment: @user3168226 yes it looks like `VideoFileReader` doesn't like .avi videos.

Comment: Hi @AdiShavit, you are correct. My mistake looking at the wrong image, There is only horizontal flip. Do you know how can i solve this problem ? is there a way to reset y axis so that it is pointing downward?

Comment: @user3168226: I guess you can always `flipud`. This might come from the `AVI` format which save the images this way.

Comment: `flipud` only works for 2D matrices.  If you want to rotate a colour image / frame (which will inevitably be the case), use `imrotate` and specify 180 degrees as the rotation angle.

Comment: I'm using `flimdim`and it worked. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Most updated Matlab function to vertically flip back the frame is:

```
FlippedFrame = flip(frame,1);
```