# Finding number of frames in a video

Tags: matlab

I tried to display a video frame by frame for which I need to know the total number of frames. But it shows an error: "unable to determine the number of frames in this file".

```
obj = VideoReader('a.avi');
nof=obj.NumberOfFrames;
for i=1:nof
    img = read(obj,i);
    imshow(img);

end
```

Comment: It seems that Matlab's `VideoReader` is no particularly fond of `AVI` format, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27797788/2777181

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The video might be encoded with a variable frame rate, in which case MATLAB cannot detect the number of frames until it reads the last frame (as is documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html).

To find out, you should read the last frame, as suggested [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader-class.html).

```
Obj = VideoReader('varFrameRateFile.avi');
lastFrame = read(Obj, inf);
numFrames = Obj.NumberOfFrames;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vidFrames = read(readerobj);
numFrames = get(readerobj, ‘numberOfFrames’);
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab will deprecate read() and NumberOfFrames in future versions. Below are some video open and find-number-of-frames function that I use to work through the Matlab version changes. I have tested a similar version of this on a few avi files, with required codecs installed.

```
function [totalFrames] = findNumFrames(videoSrcPath, SelectedReader)
    % open video source
    if ( SelectedReader == 1 )
            % VideoReader currently has a read to random frame but will be
            % deprecated soon                
            videoSrc = VideoReader(videoSrcPath); 
    elseif ( SelectedReader == 0 )
            %vision.VideoFileReader does not have a read to random frame
            videoSrc = vision.VideoFileReader(videoSrcPath,...
               'ImageColorSpace', 'Intensity'); 
    end

    % get number of frames
    if ( SelectedReader == 1 )
        % The below read() and NumberOfFrames will be deprecated in
        % future versions and we will have to use SelectReader == 0
        % or readFrame 
        try                    
            lastFrame = read(videoSrc, inf); % need to read last frame to get the number of frames
            totalFrames = videoSrc.NumberOfFrames;                    
        catch
            warning('Problem using read - possibly deprecated. Using readFrame instead.'); 
        end

    elseif ( SelectedReader == 0 )

        totalFrames = 0;
        while( ~isDone(videoSrc) )
            step(videoSrc);
            totalFrames = totalFrames + 1;
        end
        reset(videoSrc);

    end

end
```